# googleapis bigquery listjobs not returning any results

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm testing some code to call the googleapis bigquery listjobs REST API.  I am going a get to:

https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJID/jobs

with an access token generated from a service account.  The result never includes job details, just:

```
{
  "etag": "tAZvk1k2f2GY8yHaQF7how==",
  "kind": "bigquery#jobList"
}
```

If I do the call from the bq cli tool or the "try this api" form in the docs, I go get results.  If I switch to listing datasets, I also get results.  Anything obvious wrong in the query?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [BigQuery list jobs API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) only returns jobs that were started by the user making the request. The difference between the `bq` CLI / "try this API" and your REST API call is that the `bq` CLI is making requests as your Google account, but you are using a service account for the REST API.

Set the `allUsers` query parameter to `true` to list all jobs for the project.

```
https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJID/jobs?allUsers=true
```

Note: Your service account needs to have the BigQuery Admin IAM role in order to make such a request.